# Mean, Median, Mode of Log Normal Distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, median, lognormal-distribution, mode

Let $Y$ be Log-Normal with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^{2}$. So $Y=e^{x}$ with $X \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right)$. Which of the following statements is correct?

(A) The median of $Y$ is $e^{\mu}$ because the median of $X$ is $\mu$ and      the exponential function is continuous and strictly increasing, so the event $Y \leq e^{\mu}$ is the same as the event $X \leq \mu .$

(B)The mode of $Y$ is $e^{\mu}$ because the mode of $X$ is $\mu$, which corresponds to $e^{\mu}$ for $Y$ since $Y=e^{x}$.

(C) The mode of $Y$ is $\mu$ because the mode of $X$ is $\mu$ and the     exponential function is continuous and strictly increasing, so    maximizing the PDF of $X$ is equivalent to maximizing the PDF of $Y=e^{x}$.

How do I proceed with this? I know that the median condition is not true? But do we have some expression for mode?

Reference: This problem is from Chapter 6 of *Introduction to Probability* by Blitzstein and Hwang.

Comment: Should (C) say the mode of $Y$ is $e^\mu$?  Should (B) say "mean" rather than "mode"? How do you know (A) is not true?

Comment: For a distribution with a continuous probability density function $f(y)$, one definition of "mode" is $\arg\max\limits_y f(y)$, the value of $y$ which maximises $f(y)$

Comment: Have you looked at the Wikipedia article for information about the mode? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution

Comment: (C) is nonsense.  (B) is a subtle but (perhaps) common misunderstanding of the effects of transformations.  How to show that?  One way is to use Calculus: the mode will lie either at a boundary of the support, at a point where the density is not differentiable, or (as is obvious for Lognormal distributions) at a zero of the derivative of the density.  That should cause you to rethink your assessment of (A).